# Menú contextual según ítems de una TreeTableView

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo un control `TreeTableView` y he definido un menú contextual emergente cada vez que se señala un ítem del control con el botón derecho del ratón. Lo que quiero es que en función de la información contenida en cada ítem se muestre un menú contextual diferente ya que hay ítems que pueden editarse y eliminarse y otros que sólo pueden editarse.

El código que indico a continuación funciona bien pero el menú contextual siempre es el mismo para todos los ítems de la tabla:

En la clase controladora defino una factoría para las filas de la tabla:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

   private static TreeTableView<TipoDato>
        treeTableViewClasificaciónActividades = new TreeTableView<>();
   // ... código irrelevante
   treeTableViewClasificaciónActividades.setRowFactory(new Factory());    
   // ... más código irrelevante
}
```

Y la clase factoría:

```
public class Factory implements Callback<TreeTableView<TipoDato>,TreeTableRow<TipoDato>> {

        @Override
        public TreeTableRow<TipoDato> call(TreeTableView<TipoDato> p) {
            TreeTableRow<TipoDato> fila = new TreeTableRow<TipoDato>() {
            };

            MenuItem ítemEditar = new MenuItem("Editar");
            ítemEditar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    // código para editar ítem...
                }   
            });
            MenuItem ítemBorrar = new MenuItem("Borrar");
            ítemBorrar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    // código para borrar ítem...
                }
            });

            final ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();      
            rowMenu.getItems().addAll(ítemEditar, ítemBorrar);

            // solo muestra menú contextual para ítems no nulos
            fila.contextMenuProperty().bind(
              Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(fila.itemProperty()))
              .then(rowMenu)
              .otherwise((ContextMenu)null));                          

            return fila;   
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es la solución más elegante pero cumple con lo que creo que solicitas y es tener un menú emergente
diferente en función del contenido de cada fila del `TreeTableView` (También funciona para `TableView`).
Creamos un evento en el botón derecho del ratón dentro del método 'call' de la clase 'Factory'
y luego miramos el contenido de la fila y en función de éste escogemos el menú adecuado:

```
public class Factory implements Callback<TreeTableView<TipoDato>,TreeTableRow<TipoDato>> {

    @Override
    public TreeTableRow<TipoDato> call(TreeTableView<TipoDato> p) {
        TreeTableRow<TipoDato> fila = new TreeTableRow<TipoDato>() {
            };

        MenuItem ítemEditar = new MenuItem("Editar");
        ítemEditar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    // código para editar ítem...
            }   
        });
        MenuItem ítemBorrar = new MenuItem("Borrar");
        ítemBorrar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    // código para borrar ítem...
                }
            });

    final ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();      
    rowMenu.getItems().addAll(ítemEditar, ítemBorrar);
    rowMenu2.getItems().addAll(ítemEditar);  // menú Editar
    rowMenu3.getItems().addAll(ítemBorrar);  // menú Borrar

    fila.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
        if (event.getButton()== MouseButton.SECONDARY && (! fila.isEmpty())) {
            ÍtemClasificaciónActividad item = fila.getItem();                                          

                // Asumiendo que la clase 'TipoDato' tiene un método llamado 'getMenuType'
                // que devuelve un entero
            switch (item.getValue().getMenuType()){
                case 1:                           
                    fila.setContextMenu(rowMenu); // menú Editar y Borrar
                    break;
                case 2:                            
                    fila.setContextMenu(rowMenu2); // menú Editar
                    break;
                case 3:                               
                    fila.setContextMenu(rowMenu3); // menú Borrar
                    break;                  
            }            
        }
    });                      

            return fila;   
        };
    }
```

Otra solución podría ser deshabilitar opciones de un único menú que no se permitan:

```
    final ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();      
    rowMenu.getItems().addAll(ítemEditar, ítemBorrar);

fila.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getButton()== MouseButton.SECONDARY && (! fila.isEmpty())) {
        ÍtemClasificaciónActividad item = fila.getItem();                                          

        switch (item.getValue().getMenuType()){
           case 1:
              ítemBorrar.setDisable(false);
              ítemEditar.setDisable(false);            
              break;
           case 2:
              ítemBorrar.setDisable(true);
              ítemEditar.setDisable(false);                            
              break;
           case 3: 
              ítemBorrar.setDisable(false);
              ítemEditar.setDisable(true);                             
              break;                    
        }
```